# not getting the values by using request.getparameter

Tags: jsp

On click `submit` I call this function:

```
function submitFunction()
{

    document.forms[0].action = "Result.jsp";

    document.forms[0].method = 'GET';

    document.forms[0].submit();

}
```

the data in `Result.jsp` is:

```
<%
out.println(request.getparameter("demo1")+"<BR>");
out.println(request.getparameter("demo2")+"<BR>");
out.println(request.getparameter("demo3")+"<BR>");
out.println(request.getParameter("demo4")+"<BR>");  
out.println(request.getParameter("demo5")+"<BR>");
out.println(request.getParameter("demo6")+"<BR>");
%>
```

My Form:

```
<form method="post" action="Result.jsp" >
    <h1>Student Info</h1>
    <hr>
    <pre>
        <b>Name</b> :<input id="demo1" type="text" value=" "/>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <b>Age </b> :<input id="demo2" type="text" value=" "/>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <b>Qualification</b> :<input id="demo3" type=isNaN value=" "/>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <b>Address</b> :<input id="demo4" type="text" value=" "/>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <b>Company Name</b> :<input id="demo5" type="text" value=" "/>
    </pre>
    <pre>
        <b>Height</b> :<input id="demo6" type="numeric" value=" " />
    </pre>
</form>
```

please suggest solution for this

Comment: "p" in `getParameter()` function should be capital.

Comment: thanx for ur response but still i am gettting null values

Comment: <form method="post" action="Result.jsp" >

<h1>Student Info</h1>
<hr>


<pre><b>Name</b>           :<input id="demo1" type="text" value=" "/>
</pre>


<pre><b>Age </b>           :<input id="demo2" type="text" value=" "/>
</Pre>

<pre><b>Qualification</b>  :<input id="demo3" type=isNaN value=" "/>
</pre>


<pre><b>Address</b>        :<input id="demo4" type="text" value=" "/>
</pre>


<pre><b>Company Name</b>   :<input id="demo5" type="text" value=" "/>
</pre>


<pre><b>Height</b>         :<input id="demo6" type="numeric" value=" " />
</pre>


</form>

Comment: `getParameter()` uses the `name` attribute of the `input type`. Change the `input` tags to add 'name' attribute with its value same as `id`

Comment: Something like `<input id="demo4" name="demo4" type="text" value=" "/>`

Comment: hey its working thanks a lot..., can i ask u 1 more question

Comment: <pre><b>Age </b> :<input id="demo2" type="text" value=" "/> </Pre>

Comment: for this how can we restrict only number not text

Comment: @user2143146 Mostly nobody is going to answer a separate question in the comments for you, you need to ask another separate question to get an answer. That is how Stack-Overflow works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use the attribute `name` instead of `id` in your html `<form>`'s `<input>` tag:

Instead of:

```
<input id="demo1" type="text" value=" "/>
```

Use:

```
<input id="demo1" name="demo1" type="text" value=" "/>
```

Notice the `name="demo1"`. Since the key-value request pair sent to the server as request parameter is the `name-value` pair of the `<input>` i.e. `request.getParameter("demo1")` identifies the parameters through `name` & not `id`.

Also as a side-note, you can use CSS or inline-styles to style your html tags like `<input>`, `<form>` etc, rather than using the `<pre>` tag. The `<pre>` tag is generally used for displaying code or preformatted user-content.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<input id="demo1" type="text" value=" "/>`  to

```
  <input id="demo1" name = "demo1" type="text" value=" "/>
```

Add `name` attribute to all `form elements`

request.`getParameter` method  uses `name` attribute to recognize the `Form elements`

Comment: kudos.  :) .mark it as answer if its useful.