# Servlet to jsp on button click - whats the error?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a simple form on a jsp page, as given below. On clicking the button, it should take us to a servlet by the name of LoginValidation. But it doesn't work.

```
  <form name="login_form" action="LoginValidation" method="get" onsubmit="return func()" >
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="style-4" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass" class="style-4" />
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="Sign_button" "/>
  </form>
```

Here's func():

```
   function func()
        {  
            var filter="";
            var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
            var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
            if(uname==filter && pass==filter)
                {
                    alert('Please enter your username and password to sign in.');
                    return false;

                }
            else if(uname==filter)
                {
                    alert('Please enter your username to sign in.');
                    return false;
                }
            else if(pass==filter)
                {
                    alert('Please enter your password to sign in.');
                    return false;  
                }
                else
                    return true;
        }
```

xml mapping (LoginValidation is in package Controller):

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginValidation</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller.LoginValidation</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginValidation</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginValidation</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Basically, on login, func() runs. If value is true, it should ideally go to the LoginValidation servlet. But the function is not running as well. This same thing is running in another project of mine when I did it earlier. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting where is the code getting hung up? Is the `func()` function being called? Is there an error in there? Is the form being submitted to servlet? Is there an error in the servlet? `"But it doesn't work"` doesn't give us a whole lot to go on...

Comment: When I click the button it just sort of refreshes and does nothing. No alert, no travelling towards where it should travel. Nothing.

Comment: I have tried the same code you have posted and it works for me. I am able to see the alerts, also i have defined a servlet and could get the parameters

Comment: And also you should use name instead of id in <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="style-4" /> if you want to get the value of username in servlet. request.getParameter("username") will not give u the value in the servlet, u should use name="username" in your input field,because request parameters are name value pairs. Also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265256/not-getting-the-values-by-using-request-getparameter

Comment: This code is working in a separate jsp for me, meaning its correct. But, if I run it in another jsp it gives a problem. Any reason why a same piece of code may behave differently in different places?

Comment: I think something was interfering with it, I don't know what. I pulled the code apart piece by piece and transferred it another jsp. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried out the code in a separate jsp, picking up sections and pasting them, removing extra div's. Seemed to make it work.